# How do you append sequential elements when looping through a list?

Tags: python

I'm creating a bigram function, where the parameter is a list of words, and I want to return a new list that appends two consecutive words.

For example, if this was the text:

```
text = '''
it was the best of times
it was the worst of times
it was the age of wisdom
it was the age of foolishness
'''
```

I want the output to be:

```
[('it', 'was'), ('was', 'the'), ('the', 'best'), ('best', 'of'), ('of', 'times'), ('times', 'it'), ('it', 'was'), ('was', 'the'), ('the', 'worst'), ('worst', 'of'), ('of', 'times'), ('times', 'it'), ('it', 'was'), ('was', 'the'), ('the', 'age'), ('age', 'of'), ('of', 'wisdom'), ('wisdom', 'it'), ('it', 'was'), ('was', 'the'), ('the', 'age'), ('age', 'of'), ('of', 'foolishness')]
```

I know I need to loop through the list of words, but I'm unsure of how to append the consecutive elements together. **I should note that I do not want to use any libraries or the `zip` function to solve this.**

Here is what I have:

```
def bi_grams(tokens):
  bigram = []
  for word in tokens:
    bigram.append([[word], [???]])
  return bigram
```

The `???` part is where I'm stuck on. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't want to use `zip` function so,

**Find my solution for you:**

```
word_list = ['this', 'is', 'python', 'for', 'you']
result = []

for i in range(len(word_list)-1):
    result.append((word_list[i],word_list[i+1]))

print(result)
```

**Result:**

```
[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'python'), ('python', 'for'), ('for', 'you')]
```

**As per your code:**

```
def bi_grams(tokens):
    bigram = []
    for i in range(len(tokens)-1):
        bigram.append((tokens[i], tokens[i+1]))
    return bigram
```

You can always use `zip` function as easiest method as below:

```
bigram = list(zip(tokens, tokens[1:]))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Variables should not contain uppercase letters! In general, variables should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Not only that, calling a variable `list` is a terrible idea!

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` is one of the easiest methods:

```
bigram = list(zip(tokens, tokens[1:]))
```